# PHP (Inc. php-fpm) 5.4 to 5.6 - 404 not found

Tags: php, nginx, centos7

At the moment I have a LEMP setup. I had PHP 5.4 including php-fpm, but I wanted to upgrade so I removed 5.4 and replaced it with 5.6. Everything was working perfectly before. I changed the listen to

`listen = /var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock`, along with

```
listen.owner = nobody
listen.group = nobody
user = nginx
group = nginx
```

And restarted Nginx and php-fpm with no success. It's not my Nginx conf as it was working absolutely perfectly before I replaced PHP 5.4. At the moment I'm using CentOS 7. The error being displayed when I go to my site is 404 not found:

[image]

Comment: It's a bit difficult to help your without logs or some other scripts.

Comment: I actually fixed this. Now when doing service nginx restart is says: Failed to restart nginx.service: Unit not found.

Comment: @user8426498 please provide your comment as an answer and approve it so this question can be closed correctly